# Why does istream_iterator<unsigned char, unsigned char> throw std::bad_cast?

Tags: c++, stl, iostream, istream, istream-iterator

What is going on?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::basic_stringbuf<unsigned char> buf;
    std::basic_istream<unsigned char> stream(&buf);
    // the next line throws std::bad_cast on g++ 4.4
    std::istream_iterator<unsigned char, unsigned char> it(stream);
}
```

I've tried `stream.write(some_array, sizeof(some_array)` before constructing the iterator, to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Passes without any hiccups on VS8, but I wouldn't believe it !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It throws from sentry object's constructor where it checks the ctype facet on the stream (it needs it so it can skip whitespace), which happens to be NULL because it's not defined for unsigned chars.

Do you need to handle whitespace on that stream? If not, change to

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char> it(stream);
```

Comment: Yes, this does it. Alternatively, I guess `stream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws)` has the same effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt it be:

```
std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> it(stream);
```

Comment: That doesn't compile. ("no matching function for call to std::istream_iterator...")